# Can I connect Raspberry Pi to laptop screen?

Tags: screen

I have a raspberry pi kit but I don't have a screen. All I have is an android tablet and a laptop.

Can I connect it to one of them to see the screen?

Comment: vnc is probably what you're looking for. There are some questions on that around. Have a look (sorry for not pointing to them right now, but slow mobile device troubles me).

Answer (score 4):

No, sadly, this is not easily achievable without extra hardware.

What you can do is connect to the Pi via network and `ssh` either from your laptop or from your tablet, but that requires the Pi to be properly set up.