# Fresh NOOBS install boots straight to Raspbian?

Tags: pi-3, noobs

I recently purchased a Raspberry Pi 3, with a NOOBS sd card. During my first boot-up and initial setup using an external screen and keyboard, I was expecting a configuration settings dialog to choose my OS. However, I noticed it went straight into Raspbian. Is that normal?

Comment: For wireless connection between your Pi and computer I would suggest using a piece of software like VNC. It's similar to SSH but will essentially load a window on your computer of what the Pi would be outputting through HDMI. HDMI between your computer and Pi is not going to achieve this.

Comment: Welcome -- you will find [several versions of the question regarding use of a laptop display here](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/44782/can-i-connect-raspberry-pi-to-laptop-screen), with answers (in short: no), so I have edited that out and focused the question more on the NOOBs boot issue (which I can't answer as I haven't used it).

Comment: are you sure, to have NOOBS on your SD Card? Sound for me that there is Raspbian on the SD Card. To ensure that your raspberry runs NOOBs go to https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/noobs/ download NOOBS and copy it on the SD Card. You will find tons of tutorials how to copy the OS Image to the SD Card.

Comment: This is the SD card I used without any modification: http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/secure-digital-cards/9176317/

Comment: The description still says that I need to install the operating system I would like to use with the Pi. But again, I was not given any option to install my preferred operating system, and it booted straight to the Raspbian GUI. How is this possible? Was I given used items, and not new?